# Running Selenium Chrome on a server

Tags: python, selenium

There's a page I need to scrape which contains javascript and html. When I run a Selenium Chrome browser and save the page to a file, I get a result I need. However, it doesn't work with PhanthomJS -- I get a pretty different html code, even if I add this string to it as a user agent:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"
```

The reason I need PhanthomJS is because I'll need to run it on a server where, of course, will be no display.

1) Why are the results different in for Chrome and PhanthomJS?

2) Since Chrome selenim creates a visible window, is it ok and possible at to run it as it is on server? Or should I somehow to hide the window? How?

3) Or should I instead run only PhanthomJS on a server because it creates no window?

Comment: I believe you'll have the same issue with both drivers on a system with no screen. But you can make a virtual screen for either of them.

Comment: Why is it that you'd like to use Selenium to scrape a web page? Selenium is more like a test automation tool.